# How to get and align items through AsyncStorage in React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to get and align items through AsyncStorage in React native.

The following list is my requirement about my App.

1. Each user input string data into each form on a screen.
2. AsyncStorage saves that data after a user input.
3. User goes back or moves to another page.
4. User comes back to a previous screen.
5. All of the data a user did input before can show.

Below is my code.
Now I can do that for only one item.("fullname" in the following code)
But I want to do the same thing to all of the items.

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
  this.state = {
   fullname: '',
   middleName: '',
 }
}


componentDidMount() {
AsyncStorage.getItem('fullname')
  .then((text) => {
    if (text !== null) {
      console.log(text);
      this.setState({ fullname: text });
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
 }


 <QuestionTextSet
      onChangeText={(text) => {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('fullname', text);
        this.setState({ fullname: text });
      }}
      placeholder={'例：留学太郎'}
      value={this.state.fullname}
      editable
    >
      姓名（漢字表記）
    </QuestionTextSet>
    <QuestionTextSet
      onChangeText={(text) => {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('middleName', text);
        this.setState({ middleName: text });
      }}
      value={this.state.middleName}
      editable
    >
      本名以外に旧姓・通称名(通名)・別名など他の名前があればローマ字で記入
    </QuestionTextSet>
```

Comment: You can store the data in navigation params but the standard way should be to use some persistent library with redux-saga or redux thunk

Comment: try using this as well https://github.com/FidMe/react-native-fast-storage

Comment: Thank you. But I cannot use that because I am a junior Engineer and I have no time to learn that now. Of course, I have to learn and use it later but now I cannot.
So, I wanna know how to do this without redux stuff like that .